# Search two properties with ol.control.SearchFeature from ol-ext library in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, search, ol-ext

I want to search by two columns of the database.

Right now i have this code:

```
  var search = new ol.control.SearchFeature({
    placeholder: 'Search',
    source: vectorSource,
    maxItems: 20,
    property:  'name',
    
  });
  map.addControl (search);
```

Comment: So one of your "columns" is `name`, and the other is ...?

Comment: the other column would be `adress`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `property` option you can use `getTitle` option to specify/construct search property.

With `getTitle` option you specify a function that takes a feature and return the name to display in the search index (see http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/doc/doc-pages/ol.control.SearchFeature.html).

In your case code could then loke something like this:

```
function getTitle(feature) {
  var searchedTxt = feature.get('name') + ', ' + feature.get('adress');
  return(searchedTxt);
}

var search = new ol.control.SearchFeature({
  placeholder: 'Search',
  source: vectorSource,
  maxItems: 20,
  getTitle: getTitle
});
map.addControl (search);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it works perfectly

Comment: If answer helped you solve you problem, it's customary on GIS SE site to mark it as accepted, to let others with similar problems know that problem was resolved.